# Change color on tabs above the editor in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: themes, visual-studio-2022

I like the dark+ theme from the Visual Studio Theme Pack. Only problem is that it is difficult to distinguish between the selected tab and all the other tabs.

One solution would be to change the color of the tab or the text inside the tab to make it stand out. How can I do such a color change?

I have been looking for a color setting for the editor tabs in Options | Fonts and Colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on one of your tabs and select `Set Tab Layout`->`Options`

Tick the option `Colorize document tabs by:`

Now if you right click the tabs again, you will see  new option `Set Tab Color`

Comment: Thanks alot. I did not think of right clicking. That is a good solution.